# Cannot migrate with foreign key in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, database-migration, laravel-5

I want to create two table `users` and `roles`. My codes are below:

**2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('role')->unsigned();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

**2016_03_09_004256_create_roles_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('roles');
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` the following error appear.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `trucking`.`#sql-1240_44` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint u
>     sers_role_foreign foreign key (`role`) references `roles` (`id`))
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `trucking`.`#sql-1240_44` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make sure, your `roles` table migration is running before `users` table migration. By default in Laravel you have `users` table migration created, so if only you changed it's code and later added `roles` migration it won't work. You should change `users` or `roles` migration file name to make sure timestamp at the beginning of `roles` table migration file will be before `users` table.

For example you might have situation like this:

```
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
2015_10_12_123552_create_roles_table.php
```

and you should rename files to have it like this:

```
2015_10_12_123652_create_users_table.php
2015_10_12_123552_create_roles_table.php
```

Of course I assume you are using those migrations only during development and it's not on production yet.

Comment: @smartrahat No problem. You need to remember that you can create foreign key only into existing table, so sometimes you need to create 2 migrations (without foreign keys) and in 3rd migration add foreign keys between tables.

Comment: Thanks for this tips. I will remember it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->text('slug');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->decimal('fidbonus', 6, 2);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('Userinfos', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->integer('User_id')->unsigned();
           $table->foreign('User_id')->references('id')->on('Users');
           $table->string('address');
           $table->string('address2');
           $table->text('city');
           $table->string('zip');
           $table->string('country');
           $table->string('Phone');
           $table->timestamps();
       });
       Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->string('email')->index();
           $table->string('token')->index();
           $table->timestamp('created_at');
       });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think we can write more than 1 'up()' method. If required, in the same 'up()' method, you can use 'Schema::create()' twice, one below the other.

Comment: yea i copied and paste it wrong, but thats it , ill edit it and add and exemple from my own project , thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->text('slug');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->decimal('fidbonus', 6, 2);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('Userinfos', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       //$table->integer('User_id')->unsigned();
       $table->unsignedInteger('User_id');
       //$table->foreign('User_id')->references('id')->on('Users');
         $table->foreign('User_id')->references('id')->on('Users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
       $table->string('address');
       $table->string('address2');
       $table->text('city');
       $table->string('zip');
       $table->string('country');
       $table->string('Phone');
       $table->timestamps();
   });
   Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('email')->index();
       $table->string('token')->index();
       $table->timestamp('created_at');
   });
}
```

try for above code.Its working fine